# How to set an imageView with variable image?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, imageview, drawable

Sorry if the title is confusing, but I'm kind of confused as to how to ask this question.

I have a custom adapter for a listview that has an imageview in it. the image displayed is going to be different for each item in the listview. I've entered information about the listview items, including the names of their respective images (as text) in an SQLite database, that I'm attaching to my app in the assets/databases directory.

I obviously cannot use `imageView.setImageResource(R.id.<name of image file>)` because the image file being shown is dependent on which item in the listView the adapter is displaying, so I cant code it into the custom adapter class.

I've found one answer which is to use `Resources.getIdentifier()` but the documentation for that says its use is strongly discouraged, so I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Hmm I have a similar thing where I use a spinner that I then pick an item from and then the information gathered from that populated a seekbar. Once I pick a segment on the seekbar, it populates the `imageview`. However, I am using Glide to do all that. You might want to look into that because they have a `.into(imageview)` ability.

Answer (score 0):

You can store Image Resources ids in ArrayList or List. Then you can set Image Resources according to imageView position.

Make a model class with 2 variables, String for text and int for image resource id.

And make an array list of that model class type. And assign that arraylist to listview.

Learn more about ListView from android developers.